# Making query string parameters to change specific data field for RESTful APIs

Tags: node.js, rest, api, sorting

I am new to RESTful APIs and I've successfully implemented the GET and DELETE methods for my API (GET localhost:4000/api, DELETE localhost:4000/api on Postman works fine).

What I want to implement now is to specify the order in which to sort each specific field where 1 is ascending and -1 is descending. For example,

If I do localhost:4000/api/users?sort = { fieldName : 1 }

This will return a list of users sorted by 'fieldName'.

I tried to do

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var sort = req.query.sort;

  user
   .find({})
   .sort({"name": sort}) 
   .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err){
          res.status(404).send({
              message: err,
              data: []
          });
      } else {
          res.status(200).send({
              message: 'OK',
              data: users
          });
      }
  });
});
```

But since the "name" part is hard-coded, it only works for names. I want to let the user specify the field name and sort the list based on it.

What do I have to add?

EDIT: This is how my data looks like

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "59faba588f3f6211ac7db43c",
            "name": "Kim2",
            "email": "kk2@gmail.com",
            "__v": 0,
            "dateCreated": "2017-11-02T06:25:28.225Z",
            "pendingTasks": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "59facf56e8c5663343d4b644",
            "name": "Minnie Payne",
            "email": "minnie@gmail.com",
            "__v": 0,
            "dateCreated": "2017-11-02T07:55:02.552Z",
            "pendingTasks": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "59fb699c3c00c60990fa6edb",
            "name": "jerry watson",
            "email": "jerry@wgmail.com",
            "__v": 0,
            "dateCreated": "2017-11-02T18:53:16.637Z",
            "pendingTasks": []
        }, ...
```

**EDIT2**

```
  user
   .find({})
   .sort('name') 
   .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err){
          res.status(404).send({
              message: err,
              data: []
          });
      } else {
          res.status(200).send({
              message: 'OK sorted',
              data: users
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: `req.query` items all all "strings". If you want an object from JSON as parameter values, then use `JSON.parse`. i.e `.sort({ name: JSON.parse(req.query.sort) })` where `req.query.sort` is the "string" `'{ "fieldName": 1 }'`. Noting that JSON expects quoted "keys".

Comment: Sorry, could you actually elaborate your solution in the answer? I think I get the idea, but I really don't get how to do this in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to name an object property by a string.
To do it you can do something like:

```
var string = 'name'
var obj = {}
obj[string] = 'val'
console.log(obj) // {name: 'val'}
```

So, in your example:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var sort = req.query.sort;
  var name = req.query.name;
  var obj = {}
  obj[name] = sort

  user
   .find({})
   .sort(obj) 
   .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err){
          res.status(404).send({
              message: err,
              data: []
          });
      } else {
          res.status(200).send({
              message: 'OK',
              data: users
          });
      }
  });
});
```

EDIT: solution with localhost:4000/api/users?sort={fieldName: 1}

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  let obj = JSON.parse(req.query.sort)

  user
   .find({})
   .sort(obj) 
   .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err){
          res.status(404).send({
              message: err,
              data: []
          });
      } else {
          res.status(200).send({
              message: 'OK',
              data: users
          });
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: But isn't this pretty much hard coding the field 'name' ? I want to specify the field name on the URL directly. e.g. localhost:4000/api/users?sort={fieldName: 1} where fieldName can be any existing field like 'name', 'id', 'date', etc.

Comment: it's exactly what the code does! look at line 3. The name variable is taken from query string

Comment: Thanks! I just tried but it seems like it's not sorting. What I actually wanted was sorting based on whether the value for the sort query is -1 or 1 (1- ascending; -1 - descending). So that http://localhost:3000/api/users?sort={"name": 1} this would sort the names in ascending order.

Comment: if you want to pass directly {"name":1} in the query string, you need to parse string. So obj = JSON.parse(req.query.fieldname)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what I am missing, but it seems like I have to hard code the field name into the code. How could I make the code to understand what I typed in as the field name in the URL and sort based on the field name? What you are telling me to do is putting the field name that I want to sort into the code. Isn't it?

Comment: BTW, i added how my data looks like in my EDIT

Comment: no. i proposed you two solution. the first one (in my answer, where a edited your code) you can use your api in this way: localhost:3000/api/users?name=yourkey&sort=1. Then, my 2nd comment i proposed an alternative solution based on your querystring format (you want to send to server localhost:3000/api/user?sort={yourkey: 1}. In this scenario, you should JSON.parse(req.query.sort). This will create an object that you can pass to your sort function. Both the solution are not hardcoded and take the key name you want order to from query string.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. I get your idea, but I am really having trouble putting everything into code. Could you provide another code sample? To make  localhost:3000/api/user?sort={yourkey: 1} this query work?

Comment: Thanks! I think I am almost getting there. If you see my new EDIT, i tried to test it by hard-coding the 'name' field. I am having two problems here. It sorts fine but, 1) Upper-case letters come before lower-case regardless, 2) inputting -1 and 1 gives me the same output. How can I make it understand the -1 or 1 keyword? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depend from your ORM lib, I dont know which one are you using. Also, those questions are not related to the original one, you should create a new question and provide a sample code with the name of the libraries you are using. Or better, take a more accurate look to your orm's documentation